# jQuery SmartCart - Show Selected Options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, shopping-cart

I'm not good at this and trying to use this jquery smartcart, really cool and useful project.
I want to show selected options/radios (Like size, color etc.) in my cart.
Project example page here http://techlaboratory.net/projects/demo/jquery-smart-cart/v3/basic

Thanks in advance

Comment: please provide the relevant part of your code (if inside snippet even better) in your question and where exactly you are having problems

Comment: its not like a problem. the library works well but when user selects options for an item (like color, size), it doesnt show up in the cart. I'm trying to find a workaround but i dont know where to find it.
the project source https://github.com/techlab/jquery-smartcart/blob/master/src/js/jquery.smartCart.js